# Mostrar el primer elemento de un array

Tags: php

Tengo un problema con un `array, tiene el siguiente formato:

```
$array = [{"id": 1,"nombre": "Disco Duro"}];
```

Actualmente lo consumo de la siguiente manera `$array[0]` accediendo a la posición del array pero lo que intento es usar el `$array` sin la posición.

El resultado que edseo obtener es el siguiente:

```
$array = {"id": 1,"nombre": "Disco Duro"};
```

Sin los `[]`, pero sin acceder al elemento `[0]`

Comment: que quieres hacer? mostrar el valor? asignar el arreglo a otro arreglo? No es claro

Comment: Igual al comentario anterior, que deseas hacer ? Además un array en ese formato, es decir asociativo pero con : en lugar de => tiene forma de estar en formato JSON. Saludos.

Comment: Lo que trato es que ese Objeto se convierta en un array simple que no tenga []

Comment: de hecho si le dejas los símbolos de {} tampoco es un array válido en PHP

Comment: los formatos de array de clave valor como tu lo muestras en PHP son de la siguiente manera $array = array("id"=> 1,"nombre"=> "Disco Duro");

Comment: De hecho es un JSON, pero al momento de acceder debo utilizar [0] y es eso lo que trato de evitar.

Comment: Carlos no entiendo bien cuál es el alcance de tu pregunta, en parte porque tampoco explicas el uso que quieres darle a los datos posteriormente. Creo que la respuesta correcta  a tu requerimiento sería esta: Si `$array = '[{"id": 1,"nombre": "Disco Duro"}]';`y quieres una variable que te permita usar la clave `0` de `$array`, entonces aquí la tienes: `$array=$array[0];`  ahora `$array` será una cadena con este contenido: `{"id": 1,"nombre": "Disco Duro"}` Creo que lo que daría sentido a tu pregunta sería el uso final de los datos... o quizá el origen de los mismos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para que puedes acceder al elemento `[0]` puedes realizar lo siguiente.
basándome en tu ejemplo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f8abc47768f1c86ddb773b23a222108f5d931a5f

Todo está OK, pero si solo quieres tener el elemento `[0]` Ya no pongas los `[]` dentro del foreach.

Tu codigo:

```
foreach (json_decode($array, true) as $value){
    $simpleArray[] = $value;
}
```

Nuevo codigo:

```
foreach (json_decode($array, true) as $value){
    $simpleArray = $value;
}
```

Con eso no habrá ninguna necesidad de usar acceder al elemento `[0]`

Comment: Tienes razón, se me pasó por alto, muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Por que no utilizar `array_shift()`.

> array_shift() Quita el primer valor del array y lo devuelve...

Ejemplo:

```
$array = ['{"id": 1,"nombre": "Disco Duro"}']; 
$producto = json_decode(array_shift($array));

var_dump($producto); 

//acceso a datos 
echo 'Nombre: '.$producto->nombre;
echo 'id: '.$producto->id;
```

Resultado:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (2) { ["id"]=> int(1) ["nombre"]=> string(10) "Disco Duro" } 

Nombre: Disco Duro
id: 1
```

Comment: Gracias funciona de maravilla!

Answer (score 0):

Para pasar el JSON a un array asociativo, deberías utilizar la función de PHP llamada JSON_DECODE; te dejo el ejemplo de como debería ser

```
echo $array = '[{"id": 1,"nombre": "Disco Duro"}]';
$nuevo = JSON_DECODE($array, true);
```

Ahora para que puedas ver el contenido, usa la función var_dump(); que te devolverá la impresión de la clave y valor

```
echo $array = '[{"id": 1,"nombre": "Disco Duro"}]';
$nuevo = JSON_DECODE($array, true);
var_dump($nuevo);

/*imprime lo siguiente
[{"id": 1,"nombre": "Disco Duro"}]array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> 
int(1) ["nombre"]=> string(10) "Disco Duro" } }*/
```

> Ahora te comento el JSON que viene en tu variable `$array();` debes
>   meterlo entre comillas simples para que sea válido al momento de
>   transformarlo

---

> *ACTUALIZACIÓN*

Para quitar los corchetes que me mencionaste en los comentarios, se me ocurre lo hagas del modo siguiente en dos pasos con la función str_replace()

```
$array = '[{"id": 1,"nombre": "Disco Duro"}]';

$arrayUno = str_replace("[", "", $array);

$arrayDos = str_replace("]", "", $arrayUno);

echo $arrayDos;
//{"id": 1,"nombre": "Disco Duro"}

echo "<br>";

$nuevo = JSON_DECODE($arrayDos, true);

var_dump($nuevo);
//array(2) { ["id"]=> int(1) ["nombre"]=> string(10) "Disco Duro" }
```

Comment: Justo trato de evitar el elemento [0], no se como explicarme, lo que trato es que ese array sea simple por que actualmente lo debo usar así:

producto[0] y solo quiero usarlo de la siguiente manera producto

Comment: Aquí tengo un ejemplo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f8abc47768f1c86ddb773b23a222108f5d931a5f

Comment: espero con la actualización de lo último que puse te sirva de algo @AnthonySanchez en lo que agregué al final como puedes ver ya no salen los corchetes, es lo mejor que se me ocurre al momento

Answer (score 0):

Debes usar un `ArrayObject();` y lugo lo conviertes a formato **JSON** con `json_encode();`

```
$array = new ArrayObject(array(), ArrayObject::STD_PROP_LIST);
$array->id = 1;
$array->nombre = "Disco Duro";
$myJSON = json_encode($array);
echo $myJSON;
```

esto imprime solo el JSON

```
{"id":1,"nombre":"Disco Duro"}
```

Aqui lo puedes ver  [Ejecutar!](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/406471e895e6ee474229c30143d4cdead632c78d)